# Is it possible to use re.search's result in re.sub as a variable?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

**Raw text:**

> (NP (DT a) (JJ small) (NN miracle))

**text1:**

> (1-NP (2-DT 3-a) (4-JJ 5-small) (6-NN 7-miracle))**

**text2:**

> (1-NP (2-DT>1 3-a) (4-JJ>1 5-small) (6-NN>1 7-miracle))**

I want to turn text1 into text2. The purpose of this is to use **>1** to indicate number 2,4 and 6's parent is number 1.

I came up with:

```
line = '(1-NP (2-DT 3-a) (4-JJ 5-small) (6-NN 7-miracle))'
q = re.search(r'^\(([0-9]{1,2})\-NP',line)               # capture the parent number 
i = re.sub(r'( \([^ ]+\b )',r'\1' + q.group(1) ,line)    # using the captured number in re.sub
print(str(i))
```

After running the code I got the error message:

```
raise error, "invalid group reference"
sre_constants.error: invalid group reference
```

It looks like the problem is with:

```
 r'\1' + q.group(1)
```

So.. How can I turn text1 into text2 using python??

Comment: try removing r in r'\1'

Comment: Your regex only gets one match. And this will be q.group(0).

Comment: wow ..you are right. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using functions like `sub()`, expanding the parenthesized groups in the replacement string is not done in python using `\1` and `\2`,... (as in sed, awk, or vi).

Instead the groups can be referenced in the replacement string by `\g<1>` and `\g<2>`,...

```
import re

line = '(1-NP (2-DT 3-a) (4-JJ 5-small) (6-NN 7-miracle))'
q = re.search(r'^\(([0-9]{1,2})\-NP',line)
result = re.sub(r' \(([^ ]+?) ([^ ]+?)\)', ' (\g<1>>' + q.group(1) + ' \g<2>)', line)

print result
```

Note that the second regex uses `[^ ]+?` rather than `[^ ]+`. The question mark makes the `+` so-called "non-greedy", meaning it will match a part of the string as small as possible as opposed to as big as possible. The latter (as big as possible, greedy) is the default regular expression behaviour.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

```
line = '(2-NP (3-DT 4-Every) (5-NN 6-fossil))'

for i in list(re.finditer(r'\(([0-9]){0,4}\-[A-Z]{2}',line))[1:]:
    line = re.sub(re.sub('\(','\(',i.group(0)),i.group(0)+'>1',line)
print(line)
```

output

```
'(2-NP (3-DT>1 4-Every) (5-NN>1 6-fossil))'
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value